# how to make a Tab Bar without titles in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xaml, icons, tabbar

Hello everyone) I'm new to forms, sorry ...
I am making an application for android and ios. I can not remove the titles from the tab bar ...
How to make the tab bar without titles for the icons?

this is how the tab bar is made by me:

```
<Tab Icon="icon_user.png" Title="Личный кабинет">
        <ShellContent
                  
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:PersonalAreaPage}" />
</Tab>

<Tab Icon="icon_srqr.png" Title="Главная">
        <ShellContent  x:Name="homeItem"
                  
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:HomePage}" />
</Tab>

<Tab Icon="icon_settings.png" Title="Настройки">
    <ShellContent
                  
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:SettingsPage}" />
</Tab>
```

Thanks)